# Turn an anchor into a span?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the easiest way to turn an `<a>` into `<span>` keeping all the attributes and content? (except for perhaps the href).

`.replaceWith()` replaces the whole shebang.

Comment: Why? To make it unclickable?  There may be a better way - like remove the `href` attribute and adjust the styles.

Comment: I believe there's no straight forward way to do it, due to the limitation of DOM (once an element created, the tag is immutable)
I believe a combination of RegExp and .replaceWith() will do the trick

Comment: Do you want to keep event handler bindings?  What about existing references to the element... should these be updated to reference the span?

Comment: @gilly3: Yes...mostly I just want it to look identical to regular text. I don't think trying to de-style the 'a' would work very well. I'm quite positive that this code won't be updated when the styles are updated.

Comment: @gilly3: Yes. I've got an onmouseover and onmouseout on the `a` that I need to keep. There are no references to the element so those don't need to be updated. If there were, I'd use `.live` and they should continue to work. Speaking of which... I must just move the mouseover/mouseout to a `.live('hover'` or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate an element's attributes using the `attributes` property.  You can copy an attribute using `attribute.cloneNode(true)`.  You can add that cloned attribute to another element's attributes collection with `element.attributes.setNamedItem(attribute)`.

Here's a quick plugin that does it:

```
$.fn.cloneTo = function (target) {
    // copies the attributes, html, and event handlers of the first element to each of
    // the elements in the provided jQuery object or that match the provided selector
    if (!target || !target.jquery) {
        target = $(target);
    }
    if (this.length) {
        $.each(this[0].attributes, function(i, attr) {
            target.each(function(){
                this.attributes.setNamedItem(attr.cloneNode(true));
            });
        });
        $.each(this.data("events"), function(evt, handlers){
            $.each(handlers, function(i, handler){
                target.bind(evt, handler);
            });
        });
        target.empty().append(this.contents());
    }
    return this;
};
```

Use it like this:

```
var span = $("<span>");
$("#myLink").cloneTo(span).replaceWith(span);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gLqZJ/2

**Edit:** Updated above to copy event handlers and to keep the descendent nodes untouched, rather than duplicating the HTML.

Comment: Yup. That looks like it does exactly what I asked. Thanks!

Comment: If you're cloning attribute nodes, why are you copying the html contents?

Comment: @Bergi - Well said.  I've updated my answer to use `.append(this.contents())` so as to keep the original descendant elements intact.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$element.html(function(html) {
   return html.replace(/<(\/?)a/gi, "<$1span"); // string manipulation might be faster, but you get the concept
});
```

That would save the attributes and content, but not any data and event handlers. If you need those for the descendants, you should remove the child nodes and append them to the new span.

EDIT: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with jQuery. The `.html()` method changes the innerHTML, not including the node itself. The function should be something like:

```
$element(s).each(function() {
   var l = this.tagName.length + 1;
   this.outerHTML = "<span"+this.outerHTML.slice(l, -l)+"span>";
});
```

Comment: I have to agree with you, there's no way to keep the event handlers, you have to bind again.

Comment: If you want to keep the event handlers, you might wonder why you need another tag name. Shouldn't it be easier just to change the look'n'feel (CSS, preventDefault)?

Answer (score 1):

Combine jQuery's [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) and [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and copy attributes iteratively. Given your anchor tag has id `#anchor`:

```
$('#anchor').replaceWith(function() {
    var span = $('<span/>');
    $.each(this.attributes, function(){
        span.attr(this.name, this.value);
    });
    return span.html($(this).html());            
});
```

See updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gkdhj/) for an example.